# How install extension for Node in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: node.js, npm, server

I installed the WebMatrix and NPM for node. But NPM does not work shows an error:

> An error occurred.
>
> Failed: npm reported an error.
>
> NodeNpm.NpmException: Failed: npm reported an error.    at
>   NodeNpm.NpmApi.Search(String searchTerms)    at
>   Microsoft.WebMatrix.NpmGallery.CachingPackageManger.FetchRemotePackages()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

How I can install node extension?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WebMatrix is trying to use `npm search`.  This is known to be flaky, so it may take several retries for the search data to be fully downloaded and the index built.